# Get stored scroll position on click

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrollbar, scrolltop

A button, it can in anywhere in vertically centre of the page. on click on this button a popup opens and body scroll to top.
Now On click of Popup close button popup is fading out But Scroll should come to same position from where it was started.

Hard to explain Please find reference **image** and **[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/k9nL0s52/)**

[image: scroll animate jquery]

Here js code:

```
$('#popUp').click(function(e){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400);
    $('.overlay').slideDown(300, function(){
        $('.openPopup').fadeIn(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.close').click(function(e){
    $('.openPopup').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.overlay').slideUp(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: If you want the user to be where they were before they clicked it, why scroll to  top? Just make sure the popup is in the right place instead

Comment: scroll to top because in my website pop up is longer than screen and it should fit 80-90% to screen. that's why I'm scrolling body to top and popup  should start from top. I can't give position:fixed; to popup. because it needs to be scroll.

Comment: Hey Guys, can this be done without JQuery? I have a similar query in [Salesforce Stake Excahnge.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219201/how-to-detect-if-scroll-action-has-happened-in-uiscrollerwrapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k9nL0s52/2/)

[`.scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is what you want. Store it on open, then use the stored data on close.

```
var scrolltop;

$('#popUp').click(function(e){
    scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop(); // store it
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400);
    $('.overlay').slideDown(300, function(){
        $('.openPopup').fadeIn(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.close').click(function(e){
    $('.openPopup').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.overlay').slideUp(300);
    });
    //$(document).scrollTop(scrolltop); // use it
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: scrolltop}, 400); // animate to scrolltop
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, It's working. But can it again animate while scrolling down? i'm using code for that:  var $scroll = $(document).scrollTop($('#popUp').data('scroll'));
     $('body').animate({scrollTop:$scroll}, 400);

Comment: Why would you use that code? `$scroll` that you defined is a function. Maybe the update will help you make more sense of where the value is.

Comment: Thanks, Forget it. Now in your demo it's scrolling down with animation. I just Did some changes Here (http://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/k9nL0s52/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way. see here http://jsfiddle.net/k9nL0s52/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var track_position;  // this is for tracking your scrolled position

    $('#popUp').click(function(e){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 400);
    $('.overlay').slideDown(300, function(){
        $('.openPopup').fadeIn(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    track_position = $('body').scrollTop(); //get current postion
});
$('.close').click(function(e){
    $('.openPopup').fadeOut(300, function(){
        $('.overlay').slideUp(300);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').scrollTop(track_position); // set previous position after close click
});

});
```

Comment: So, virtually exactly the same answer as that which what was already posted  and accepted 17 minutes ago, except that `$('body').scrollTop()` doesn't work in IE

Comment: @Popnoodles Actually i was busy in modifying code in fiddle & didn't see you answer Sir.

Comment: This took you 17 minutes?

Comment: @NigelAngel, No it takes me 2:30 minutes. i was taking my dinner also :)